# Are these two representations correct and why?

Tags: matrices, vectors

$\vec u \times \vec v = (ai + bj + ck) \times (di + ej + fk) =  
\begin{bmatrix}
i & j & k\\
a & b & c\\
d & e & f\\
\end{bmatrix}$

And,

$\vec v = ai + bj + ck = \begin{bmatrix}
a \\
b \\
c \\
\end{bmatrix} = {\begin{bmatrix}
a & b & c\\
\end{bmatrix}}^T$

Why?

Comment: It should technically be the determinant of that matrix for the first one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's no more than a definition of the cross product. and the transpose of a matrix.